# How to get right click context menu in Windows application using Python?

Tags: python, windows, win32gui, pywinauto

How to get the right click context menu in a Windows application using Python, do not set the position of the cursor and when not focus that Windows application.

Context menu is not the Explorer context menu, it is the Windows application right click context menu.

[image]

Comment: `app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.Click(button='right')` works correctly, but the next command `app.PopupMenu.MenuSelect('Paste')` gets the Notepad window to the focus. Do you have the same kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for Notepad:

```
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.Click(button='right') # works
app.PopupMenu.MenuSelect('Paste') # seems not working when Notepad is not in focus
# though it works when app.UntitledNotepad.SetFocus() is called before
```

`app.PopupMenu.MenuSelect('Paste')` may not work in such a case because probably `WM_COMMAND` can be sent to a focused window only. To get it to work use `app.PopupMenu.MenuItem('Paste').ClickInput()` though your app window will get to focus any way.

---

So finally there are 2 working examples. The first is:

```
app.UntitledNotepad.SetFocus()
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.Click(button='right')
app.PopupMenu.MenuSelect('Paste')
```

The second is:

```
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.Click(button='right')
app.PopupMenu.MenuItem('Paste').ClickInput()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i didn't get correctly answer, but got a solution or way for this problem. thansk again! : )

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the solution.